# Change 8-digit hexadecimal number(IEEE-754) single precision representation into a real number

Tags: binary, 32-bit, cpu-registers, hex

I am changing an 8-digit hexadecimal number to a real number Y.
The number is 0xAC0396ED

My question is: Shall I take into consideration the 0x? What is the significance of the 0x?
I researched it and based on wikipedia, I got this:
"use the prefix 0x for numeric constants represented in hex"

What I plan on doing is take the part AC0396ED and change it to binary, then from binary manipulate the 32 bit number byte dividing the number intro 3 parts: sign, exponent, and fraction.

My last question is why do we need hexacdecimal, decimal, octal? Why don't we just stick to binary in all our arithmetic and operations?

Thank you.

Comment: 0x is only the notation of the hexadecimal-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My question is: Shall I take into consideration the 0x? What is the significance of the 0x?*

No - you should not take that into consideration - its only a notation for hexadecimal base system

*What I plan on doing is take the part AC0396ED and change it to binary, then from binary manipulate the 32 bit number byte dividing the number intro 3 parts: sign, exponent, and fraction.*

Here is how you calculate it:

AC0396ED =>

10 12 0 3 9 6 14 13 in decimal. Then to binary

1010  1100 0000 0011 1001 0110 1110 1101

here you have all bits i.e 32 bits

```
  1 | 01011000 | 00000111001011011101101
```

so the first bit is 1 => the number is negative

the second is the exponent

the third is the mantissa

*My last question is why do we need hexacdecimal, decimal, octal? Why don't we just stick to binary in all our arithmetic and operations?*

Its much more easy to stick to hexadecimal system - compare the 32 bits to the AC0396ED